# How does one show something is not an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Sorry for the random question, in a class we are talking about affine varieties. I have a problem trying to show a set of points in $R^2$ is not an affine variety.

I just wanted to ask what is the general strategy to show something is an affine variety. Currently I understand that an affine variety is a set of points that make a set of polynomials vanish.

ie $V= V(f_1,...f_n)$
I am thinking that I need to exhibit that there is no polynomial that vanishes at the given set. Is this the correct idea?

Comment: The techniques can be rather ad hoc based on the situation.  You should post a specific example.

Comment: And yes, you are showing that the set cannot be the zero locus of any collection of polynomials.

Comment: Sure, I just did not wanted to be specific because it is a homework problem,  here is a similar problem from the book  $$P=\{(x,y) \in R^2 : y >0 \}$$

Comment: When you say "no polynomial" you mean "no nonzero polynomial." Then the condition is sufficient but not necessary; it may be the case that some nonzero polynomial vanishes on the set but nevertheless you can't find a finite set of polynomials whose vanishing locus is *precisely* the set because any polynomial vanishing on the set in fact vanishes on a larger set; that is, in fancier words, it may be the case that a subset is not Zariski closed even though its Zariski closure may not be all of affine space.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by $R$ you mean $\mathbb R$, the real numbers.

One trick that works in your example is to note that polynomials are continuous in the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R^n$.  That means that affine varieties are not just closed in the Zariski topology, they are also closed in the Euclidean topology.

If your set is not closed in the Euclidean topology then it is not a variety.